# Syncing Hasura and Firebase Users using cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, graphql, google-cloud-functions, hasura

I am trying to sync my users between Firebase and Hasura. My Firebase function doesn't throw any errors, however, it is not updating Hasura. Can anyone explain to me the part that I am missing?

My firebase function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { request, gql, GraphQLClient } = require('graphql-request')


const config = functions.config();
const endpoint = config.hasura.url;
const adminSecret = config.hasura.admin;
const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-hasura-admin-secret": adminSecret
  }
});
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async user => {
  const { uid: id, email } = user;

  const mutation = gql`
    mutation($id: String!, $email: String) {
      insert_users_one(object: { user_firebase_id: $id, user_email: $email }) {
        user_firebase_id
        user_email
      }
    }
  `;

  try {
    const data = await graphQLClient.request(mutation, {
      id,
      email,
    });
    
    return data;

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

The logs return

```
Function execution took 521 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

```
createUser
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Hasura to answer this question, but it seems you are using a string literal template, this does introduce line spaces `\n` which may interfere.
From the Firebase side, it all appears to be ok. just make sure you return at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The string literal created a new line (`\n`) a stated a comment `@DIGI Byte`.

There are other ways but to keep it simple I changed structure of this

```
  const mutation = gql`
    mutation($id: String!, $email: String) {
      insert_users_one(object: { user_firebase_id: $id, user_email: $email }) {
        user_firebase_id
        user_email
      }
    }
  `;
```

to

```
 const mutation = gql`mutation($id: String!, $email: String)\{insert_users(objects: [{user_firebase_id: $id,user_email: $email}]) {affected_rows}}`;
```

I know there has to be a more efficient way of fixing this, but if anyone else runs into a similar issue. I'll leave this here.